# insert values to a table from watchdog

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom module which when installed it creates a table with blablabla name and uid,timestamp as fields. Now what i really want is when cron runs to get the values(uid, timestamp) from the watchdog table and pass it to my blablabla table. Is there a method to do this thing? This is my code:

```
**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function example_cron() {
      // Begin building the query.
      $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
        ->extend('PagerDefault')
        ->orderBy('wid')
        ->fields('th', array('uid', 'timestamp'))
        ->limit(2000);

      // Fetch the result set.
      $result = $query -> execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it :

```
f($r->rowCount() == 0) {
    $query = db_insert('blablabla')
      ->fields(array(
        'timestamp' => $timestamp,
        'wid' => $wid,
        'variables' => $variables,
     ))
     ->execute();
```